# correcting display in IE7 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

My code displays correctly in every browser except IE7 and I'm not sure why. I've gone through so many threads about problems in IE7 to no avail. There are six similar li tag elements. They should show up in three to a row. Here is a section of the HTML:

```
<div id="winning-designs" class="product-section">
    <h2 class="section-heading">Winning logo designs</h2>
    <ul class="winning-designs-list">
<li class="winning-design">

    <!-- thumb -->
    <a href="#" class="lightbox-trigger" title="View case study" data-lightbox-target="winning-design1-lightbox">
        <img src="/static/images/category-product-pages/logo-design/example1-thumb.png" width="268" height="160" />
        <p class="larger-link">View case study</p>
    </a>

    <!-- lightbox -->
    <div id="winning-design1-lightbox" class="lightbox winning-design-lightbox">
        <div class="lightbox-content">

            <div class="winning-design-info">
                <h3>Carplanet.com.au</h3>
                <p>Carplanet.com.au is an Australian based website that reviews new cars. They didn't have a predefined brand or color scheme in mind, so allowed designers to have complete artistic freedom for this logo.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="contest-stat">Paid <span class="symbol">$</span><span class="amount">709</span></li>
                    <li class="contest-stat">Received <a href="/logo-design/contests/car-review-company-requires-logo-36577" title="View contest">202 designs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="winning-design-feature">
                <div class="enlarged-image-wrapper">
                    <a href="/logo-design/contests/car-review-company-requires-logo-36577">
                        <img data-src="/static/images/category-product-pages/logo-design/example1-large.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</li>
```

and this is my jQuery:

```
m360_empty($("#intro-examples")); 
m360_empty($(".join-msg")); 
$(".lightbox-trigger img").width(90); 
$(".lightbox-trigger img").height(54); 
var wd_html = "<div id='winning-designs' class='product-section'>" + $('#winning-    designs').html() + "</div>";
m360_empty('#winning-designs'); 
$("#intro-examples").html(wd_html);

var ie7 = (document.all && !window.opera && window.XMLHttpRequest) ? true : false;
 if (ie7) { 
  wd_html = "<div id='winning-designs' class='product-section'>" + $('#winning-  designs').html() + "</div>";
  wd_html_ie = "<table border='0' width='440'><tr border='0'><td border='0'>" + wd_html + "</td></tr></table>";
  $("#intro-examples").html(wd_html_ie);
}

$("#winning-designs").width(440);
$("#intro-msg").width(450);

$("#lightbox").css("align", "center");

(function($) {

$('.lightbox-trigger').click(function() {
target = $(this).attr('data-lightbox-target');
$('#' + target).lightbox_me({
    centered: true
    });
return false;
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You need to shrink this down to only the relevant code.  As is, the JavaScript contains undefined function calls, and there is more markup than you need.  Also, consider creating a jsFiddle.

Comment: Where is your CSS? IE 7 has some hacks that will generally fix any layout issues you are having. For instance IE 7 doesn't know about `inline-block` so you have to include `*display:inline` to the CSS rule to target IE 7.

Comment: I ended up just writing a separate block of html just for IE7.

Comment: You should answer your own question, so that it is not marked as unanswered when it really is.

Comment: @user1090588 Please answer your own question so that others will be able to learn from your answer.

Comment: @user1090588 Make sure you answer you question dude, or remove it, either way.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i make an ie7.css stylesheet that only runs if the browser is ie7, and override any elements that don't look right, but add version 1 of `normalize.css` (`http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/`) to reset the padding, margin, etc beforehand. Also look at using clearfix (`http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html`) instead of clear:both